# C++17 enum type declaration

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following enum typedef and want to define a variable which can hold the different states.

```
typedef enum _EventType
{
    Event1 = 0x001, Event2 = 0x002, Event2 = 0x0004
}EventType;
```

This it what I want:

```
EventType type = EventType::Event1 | EventType::Event2;
```

or

```
EventType type = EventType::Event1;
type |= EventType::Event2;
```

V2017 gives me the following error:

```
 Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
```

I know that I could write:

```
   EventType type = static_cast<EventType>(EventType::Event1 | EventType::Event2);
```

But the code is not so easy to understand.

Comment: The valid enumeration values each have a single bit set.  When you try to combine them with `|`, you no longer have values from the enumeration, so you shouldn't be able to assign them to a variable of the enumeration type with bludgeoning the system (`static_cast<…>`, etc).  The variable should be of type `int`, perhaps — unless someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Note that `_EventType` is reserved identifier because it starts from underscore followed by uppercase.

Comment: Also note that `typedef enum ...` is only useful in C. In C++, you can just do `enum EventType { ... };`

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to overload bitor operator so it performs necessary conversions:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

// specifying underlaying type here ensures that enum can hold values of that range
enum class EventType: ::std::uint32_t
{
    Event1 = 0x001, Event2 = 0x002, Event3 = 0x0004
};

EventType operator bitor(EventType const left, EventType const right) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<EventType>
    (
        ::std::underlying_type_t<EventType>(left)
        bitor
        ::std::underlying_type_t<EventType>(right)
    );
}

auto combined{EventType::Event1 bitor EventType::Event2};

int main()
{
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JO2G1e9qJyTFOe4p)

Comment: Tnx for removing the typedef!

Comment: One thing left. What is with that; "type |= EventType::Event2;". Is this also possible and how?

Comment: @makurisan Other operators can be similarly overloaded as well.

Comment: Yes, I know and I tried but without success the first time. Now it works.